# Does try catch in C++ affect performance when not hit

Tags: c++, try-catch

I have code where there is a try catch in a function and the function gets hit. 100+ times. The code return early everytime without actually hitting the try catch. Does this affect performance in Visual Studio. I am seeing a performance impact.

My code was :

```
void foo(int a) {
 if (a > value) {
    return;
 }
 try {
    possibleErrorFunction();
 } catch {
 }
}
```

I changed it to:

```
void foo(int a) {
if (a > value) {
    return;
}
bar();
}

void bar() {
try {
    possibleErrorFunction();
} catch {
}
}
```

The second code seems about 10 sec faster. Is there any resaonable explanation for this?

Comment: Use a profiler to figure it out. I find it highly unlikely any performance hit would be noticable.

Comment: Ten seconds on how many iterations?

Comment: Does enabling try/catch affect performance?  A little yes.  10 seconds?  Maybe if you were running it for a few days.  @Almo is correct - profile and see where the issue really is.

Comment: It depends on your platform, and even with Visual Studio, it depends on whether you target x86, x86_64 or ARM. C++ exceptions on Windows use SEH. Setting up an exception handler has a cost, but it should be almost negligible; it should certainly not take 10 seconds.

Comment: Did you turn on optimizations (which is sort of the same as doing a Release build)?

Comment: Optimizations are off. Its a debug build. 10 seconds difference is in V- tune for foo after running an application that hits foo() 100+ times.

Comment: Profiling a debug build without optimization is pointless. Lots of extra (expensive) sanity checking code that affects performance is generated in addition to your code not being optimized. Test an optimized build and I'm sure the compiler will remove all the overhead you are seeing.

Comment: Suggest adding a tag for the particular compiler versiou you are using

Comment: With optimizations, any compiler worth its salt will produce byte-for-byte identical object code for the two cases. Even profiling without optimization (a totally useless waste of time) there's no reason whatsoever for the second program to be faster by such a huge amount  --- if anything, it should be a little bit slower. You are probably not measuring what you think you are measuring.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 major policies used in exception mechanism implementation. One is so-called "frame based", or "dynamic" and another one is "table based". Other schemes are variations of those two. You can read more about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Exception_handling_implementation)

In essence, "frame-based" dynamic implementation does spend resources on each entry into and exit from `try` block at run-time. The "table based" mechanism does not involve any extra work if exception is not thrown but it uses much more memory.

I am not 100% sure but as far as I know Microsoft compiler up till VS2008 used "frame-based" approach and starting from VS2010 it implements "table-based" approach. (Maybe there are some compiler switches that can control it - I don't know because I personally prefer not to use exceptions until forced by existing code or 3rd party libraries). I think you can find this information in your compiler documentation.

You could also produce assembler code from your c++ source to see what is going on with your `try` block

Comment: The difference with Microsoft's compiler is not the version you're using, but whether you are targeting x86-32 or x86-64. All versions will use the frame-based approach for 32-bit builds, whereas all versions will use the table-based approach for 64-bit builds (and for *all* other architectures, like Itanium, Alpha, PowerPC etc.). It is just x86-32 that is the odd man out, using the frame-based approach for exception handling as it does, and this will be true even on the latest version of the compiler. They can't change it now for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: More specifically, for the frame-based implementation on x86-32, active exception handlers are stored in a singly-linked list, and a pointer to this list is stored in the Thread Environment Block (TEB). When an exception occurs, the OS walks through that list, looking for a suitable handler. If it finds one, it executes it and unwinds the stack. If not, it invokes the unhandled exception handler. On x86-64 and all other table-based implementations, the compiler emits the tables in the code. This is faster at run-time, but bloats the size of the binary.

Comment: @CodyGray Aren't you mixing here SEH used by Windows itself and its API (Pascal-rooted) with C++ language exceptions implemented by `try`/`catch` blocks? AFAIK they are not exactly the same things.

Comment: Microsoft's compiler implements C++ exceptions using SEH. I'm not sure if that's true for *all* compilers (e.g., GCC, Clang, etc.), but it certainly is true for Visual C++.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above comments seem to converge toward a useful point or two.  Extra apparatus always engages more CPU cycles and thus derogatively affects performance (I can't believe this editing box flagged "derogatively").  Many iterations over many instances are required.

Comment: well, this is not true in general - for dwarf2 there is no penalty for `try` blocks that do not actually throw.

Comment: That would be your browser's built-in spell checker flagging "derogatively." Stack Overflow doesn't have a spell-check feature, nor does it have a dirty word filter (at least, not for answers...it does for certain words in question titles).